# Calculate total percent change from incremental changes

Tags: percentages

Is there a formula to calculate a total percent change of a value from multiple changes?

Example:

```
Initial: 100
-10%: 90
+5%: 94.5
-20%: 75.6
```

So I am looking for some formulaic way of taking the initial value of `100` and the changes of `-10%,+5%, and -20%` and giving me `75.6`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply all of the percent changes together as decimals i.e. 0.9*1.05*0.8 for your example and then multiply this number by the original value.